# VS2010 RC: Add new domain service class wizard entities list is empty

Tags: visual-studio, wcf-ria-services

Greetings!

I am going through Brad Abrams' SL4 + RIA Services series. Right now I am here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2010/03/15/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-data-from-entity-framework.aspx.

When I get to the "add domain service" step and the wizard asks you what entities you want to expose, the list is empty.  The dropdown that let's me choose my Entity data context is there and the "DishViewEntities" is selected but it is not showing the "Restaurant" and "Plate" entities in the list below like it does in the picture.

I found this thread here:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/168724.aspx.
The poster has the same problem as me.  I have restarted VS, rebooted, regenerated the EDMX, tried creating it in different folders.  Still the list is empty.  When it is empty, it will not allow me to select individual entities or generate the class.

Any ideas from the community?  Thanks!

Comment: In Brad's post, the DomainService class that gets generated inherits from LinqToEntitiesDomainService<DishViewEntities>.  LinkToEntitiesDomainService<T> is implemented in System.Web.DomainServices.EntityFramework.dll which does not exist on my machine as far as I can tell.  Shouldn't have have been included with the RIA Services install?  Where should it live on my file system?  Could that have something to do with the wizard not working right?

Comment: After deleting and creating a new project, it worked this time.  VS is a strange beast.

Comment: I'm having same issue again, now I'm rebooting for last chance bye!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.  I looked for answers on web, they all seemed to relate to installing the RiaServicesToolkit, or other packages, or the dbml confirguration string.  But I noticed that when I was opening my Linq2Sql (dbml) in visual studio that I was getting a message about the configuration string missing or incorrect.

It turns out that the configuration string problem was the result of my SQL Server Agent being set to Manual instead of Automatic in my Services (Control Panel).  Once I corrected this, the configurations string problem went away.

I don't know if that is also what was causing my RIA (Linq2SQL) problem (although I do see how it could), but after fixing this, and cleaning & rebuilding the solution, my Linq2SQL context appeared on the drop down list of the DomainService wizard and all was golden.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This happens from time to time in my project. I don't really have to create a new project (which would be very unfeasable.) I usually make sure the project builds (clean/rebuild) and right-click on edmx file and do run custom tool. And make sure that no errors are being reported on Error and/or Output windows.

Comment: I ended up reloading the project on top of this which got it working for me. I didn't get the chance to try but it might be possible that reloading the project alone may fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We solved our problem. Sometimes EDMX designer can't map Entities and tables. Right click each entity and select table mapping then ensure if all of your entities are mapped correctly.

When you want to add Domain Service Class an exception occur but (I don't know why) the exception message doesn't display. Than the list is seen empty.

If all of your mappings and web.config settings are right after rebuild progress domain service class addition works fine!

[image: Mapping Bug]